# in_array php - poo

Tags: php, array, poo, formularios

Tengo un objeto en el que hay modulos en forma de array. Lo que quiero es que al clickar en Seleccionar, en la parte derecha no me puedan aparecer repetidos. No me da errores pero no realiza la función que yo deseo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
    public function anadirAlArray($codigo) {
      $modulo=DB::consultaModulo($codigo);
      array_push($this->modulosSel, $modulo);

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="post">';
      foreach ($this->modulosSel as $modulo){
        echo '<tr>';
        $cod = $modulo->getCodigo();
        $nombre= $modulo->getNombre();

        if (in_array($nombre,$this->modulosSel)) {
          echo "Modulo existente";
        }else{
          echo '<td>'.$nombre." ".'<input type="submit" name="quitarModulo[' .$cod.']" value="Quitar">'."<br>";
          echo '</tr>';
        }
      }
      echo "</form>";
      echo '</table>';

  }
```

Comment: Si se trata de quitar módulos de un lado para ponerlos en otro y viceversa, quizá puedas escribir algo más elegante, algo así como un intercambiador que al pulsar en `Seleccionar` te pase ese elemento del otro lado y al pulsar en `Quitar` lo saque del lado derecho y lo devuelva al izquierdo. Podrías hacerlo así, a no ser que necesites íntegra la información de la izquierda para otras cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que para revisar si hay repetidos, ejecutas la línea `if (in_array($nombre,$this->modulosSel)) {...`. Pero en la línea 3, lo que estás agregando a `$this->modulosSel` no son textos sino el resultset `$modulo`.

En otras palabras, para que tu validación funcione debes modificar la línea 3 para que diga:

```
array_push($this->modulosSel, $modulo->getNombre());
```